# PyTorch, could not broadcast shape

Tags: python, pytorch

I trained an auto encoder in PyTorch with some satellite images. I'm trying to extract the embedding of the images using the code below and when I execute the `get_all_embeddings` function, I receive the following error:

`ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (3,256,256) into shape (256,256)`.

The error doesn’t seem to happen when retrieving a single embedding with `get_single_embedding`. I'm not sure where I'm going wrong here.

This process has worked previously doing the same task using a ResNet50 model - the only difference was I was trying to work with an auto encoder this time.

The images I'm using are 256x256 png images with 3 bands (R,G,B).

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torchvision.transforms as transforms

class AutoEncoder(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__()
        self.encoder_hidden_layer = nn.Linear(
            in_features=kwargs["input_shape"], out_features=128
        )
        self.encoder_output_layer = nn.Linear(
            in_features=128, out_features=128
        )
        self.decoder_hidden_layer = nn.Linear(
            in_features=128, out_features=128
        )
        self.decoder_output_layer = nn.Linear(
            in_features=128, out_features=kwargs["input_shape"]
        )

    def forward(self, features):
        activation = self.encoder_hidden_layer(features)
        activation = torch.relu(activation)
        code = self.encoder_output_layer(activation)
        code = torch.relu(code)
        activation = self.decoder_hidden_layer(code)
        activation = torch.relu(activation)
        activation = self.decoder_output_layer(activation)
        reconstructed = torch.relu(activation)
        return reconstructed

model = AutoEncoder(input_shape=256).to(device)

transform = transforms.Compose([
    transforms.ToPILImage(mode='RGB'),
    transforms.ToTensor(),
    transforms.Normalize(mean=[0.5, 0.5, 0.5], std=[0.5, 0.5, 0.5])])

def get_single_embedding(image_path, model, transform):

    device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
    image = mpimg.imread(image_path)
    image = transform(image)
    image = image.unsqueeze(0)
    image = image.to(device)
    model.eval()

    with torch.no_grad():
        embedding = model(image).to(device)

    return embedding.cpu().numpy()

def get_all_embeddings(image_paths, model, transform):
    image_embeddings = np.zeros(shape=(3, 256, 256))
    
    for idx, file in enumerate(image_paths):
        image_embeddings[idx] = get_single_embedding(file, model, transform)
    
    print(image_embeddings.shape)

    return image_embeddings

image_embeddings = get_all_embeddings(image_files, model, transform)
query_embedding = get_single_embedding(query_image, model, transform)
```

Comment: Hi @andrewr, Where exactly is the error raised? (what is `query_image`, where is `model` defined?). Maybe you have an RGB image (so with 3 channels) that you are trying to fit on a 2D array? But you could provide more information about where the error is raised and which shape would you expect from the objects involved, then it would definitely be easier to tell.

Comment: Hi! I updated with the actual AE network I used. The error I'm getting is the `ValueError` stating not able to broadcast from (3,256,256) to (256,256). I am indeed using 256x256 images with 3 bands (RGB). I did this very same task earlier with a ResNet model and the same images, so I think there may be a problem with how I'm constructing the network

Comment: With such linear layers (256 on input, 128 on output) possible way for model to work is to treat every image as batch of independent rows of length 256, thus losing 2D information (in ResNet convolution layers are used, so information get preserved). Also when calling `model(image)` in `get_single_embedding` you actually getting not embedding (low dimensional representation of original), but reconstruction of image (because that's code in `forward`), it's intentional?

Comment: The intention was to actually get the embedding, I was not aware (or misunderstood) how that was actually occurring. This might require more thought to actually accomplish the task

Comment: I agree with @draw's comment, maybe you should split into creating a script that actually trains the encoder, but with convolution, so you apply that to images [here an example](https://analyticsindiamag.com/how-to-implement-convolutional-autoencoder-in-pytorch-with-cuda/), and then do inference using that trained model to actually get the embeddings.